# change multiple series chartType without iteration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

I have an asp.net 4.0 chart generated with DataBindCrossTable from LINQ db query.
That creates chart with multiple series (27 in my case).

Is there a way to change chartType on all those auto generated series without iteration over them ? This is what I'm doing now:

```
For Each series In Chart1.Series
   series.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedBar
   series.BorderWidth = 2
Next
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think so. What is wrong with iterating over them? It won't cost hardly anything to do..